# Addition and substraction from two tables on mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, operators, addition

I am trying to make a points system where you can select from 1 to 5

```
  <form class='form-horizontal' action='../api/points.php' method='post'><fieldset>
       <input type='radio' value='1' name='points' /> 1 </input>
                 <input type='radio' value='2' name='points'  /> 2 </input>
                 <input type='radio' value='3' name='points'  /> 3 </input>
                 <input type='radio' value='4' name='points'  /> 4 </input>
                 <input type='radio' value='5' name='points'  /> 5 </input>
                 <br />
                 <input name='Submit' type='submit' value='give points' />
                 <input name='userid' type='hidden' value='<? echo $row['user_id'] ?>' />
                 <input name='postid' type='hidden' value='<? echo $row['id'] ?>;' />
                 <input name='currentpoints' type='hidden' value='<? echo $row['postpoints']; ?>' />
                 <input name='user2id' type='hidden' value='<? echo $loggedInUser->user_id; ?>' />
                 </fieldset>
                 </form>
```

there are two ids, the id of the user that it's giving points and the id of the user that will receive them.

I have to store them: (1) on the posts table where it records the total number of points that post has been given. (2) the points should be substracted from the user that is giving and added to the user that posted it.

It is giving the posts the points, but it doesn't add or substract from the users table

```
$pointsvar = htmlentities($_POST['points']);
$userid = htmlentities($_POST['userid']);
$user2id = htmlentities($_POST['user2id']);
$postid = htmlentities($_POST['postid']);
$currentpoints = htmlentities($_POST['currentpoints']);
$suma1 = $currentpoints+$pointsvar;

$sql = "UPDATE ft_posts SET postpoints=(postpoints + $pointsvar) WHERE id='$postid'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "post points updated successfully";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "current post points+points variable: ";
    echo ($suma1);
        echo "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$sql2 = "UPDATE ft_users SET points='(points + $pointsvar)' WHERE id='$userid'";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "User given points updated successfully";
        echo "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record 2: " . $conn->error;
}

      $sql3 = "UPDATE ft_users SET points='(points - $pointsvar)' WHERE id='$user2id'";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "User taken points updated successfully";
        echo "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record 3: " . $conn->error;
}$conn->close();
```

Comment: Remove the quotes in `points='(points + $pointsvar)'` even do `points=points + $pointsvar` no brackets required. Same thing for the substraction. Checking for errors would have signaled an error, something you didn't tell us it was erroring out as.

Comment: Sidenote: If you're going to use short tags, you can reduce your `<? echo` down to `<?=` *Sweet huh?*

Comment: Well it started to work on the addition side (the user that receives points) but it doesn't subtract... Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: `SET points='(points + $pointsvar)'` to `SET points=(points + $pointsvar)` and `SET points='(points - $pointsvar)'` to `SET points=(points - $pointsvar)` you can even get rid of the brackets.

Comment: yup i've done that, even got rid of the brackets `$sql2 = "UPDATE ft_users SET points=points + $pointsvar WHERE id='$userid'";` and `$sql3 = "UPDATE ft_users SET points=points - $pointsvar WHERE id='$user2id'";`

Comment: `if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {` you're using that in the intention for `$sql3` so that should be `if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {`

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my answer below so you can mark it as solved; you do know how, yes?. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes in `points='(points + $pointsvar)'`
and for `SET points='(points - $pointsvar)'`

As for this line:

```
if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
```

You're using that in conjunction with `$sql3` so that should be:

```
if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
```